# Allow webview to read clipboard

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, kotlin, webview

I Have normal html file webview with input and button; i have success to make button paste the text from clipboard when i click on it; i tested the project in google chrome in pc and is working good;
i put the html file in webview with android studio and the app working and i show the page but nothing happing when i click on the button

this is part frome the webview:

```
    webframe.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html")
    webframe.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
    webframe.settings.allowFileAccess = true
    webframe.settings.domStorageEnabled = true
```

and this is html cole:

```
<input class="form-control" id="url_input" type="text" value="" />
<button id="past_btn">
  img src="images/copy.svg" width="22px" height="22px" />  
</button>

<script>
    $('#past_btn').click(function(){
        $('#url_input').not(function(){
            paste(this) ;
        });
    });
    async function paste(input) {
    const text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
    input.value = text;
    }
</script>
```

this html working in Chrome and Mozilla.
Thank You